# How to add the Geometry type LineString/ MultiLineString within the function QgsGeometryGeneratorSymbolLayer using PYQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

Within a function of pyqgis I am trying to create a layer according to multiple steps. I want to change the Geometry type option to LineString / MultiLineString in the function so that this will be done automatically. Is there a variable I can add to the function? [image]

```
shape_sym = QgsGeometryGeneratorSymbolLayer.create({'geometryModifier': 'difference(difference(make_line(start_point($geometry), centroid(offset_curve($geometry, length($geometry)/-10.0)), end_point($geometry)), buffer(start_point($geometry), 10000)), buffer(end_point( $geometry), 10000))', 'outline_color': 'black'})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, found the solution: added the line `shape_sym.setSymbolType(QgsSymbol.Line)` afterwords.